# How to make the web browser not change the scroll area after a div scroll is at the bottom?

Tags: javascript, html, css

What I want is, by default the browsers after is done scrolling a element, they just scroll the parent element

for example:

I have:

```
    <div id="main" style="height: 5000px; width: 700px; border: 2px solid black; float: left;">
    <div id="scroller" style="float: right; width: 200px; border: 2px solid black; overflow: auto; height: 60px; ">
               TEXTO<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />           
    </div>
</div>
```

If I place my mouse pointer in the div scroller and starts to scroll, when it reaches the bottom of the scroll (when theres nothing else to scroll) , it just starts to scroll the main div automatically. is there any way to not allow that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prevent the mouse wheel event from bubbling up to a parent that has a scroll bar.

To make sure the parent has no scroll bar, place both div's adjacent to each other, as follows: **[see demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/wH3M5/)**.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is no.

By the way I noticed that Firefox 7.0.1 doesn't have this behavior, if you just avoid to give focus to other divs.

Comment: Then why facebook chat and facebook ticker do that? you scroll in that area and even if it ends you don't scroll the body content.  isn't it possible by some javascript?